# Runtime Exception in login and registration classes

Tags: java, class, netbeans-8

how do I handle Exception in thread ?

Code;

```
private static void main(String[] args) {
  Login_WE h = new Login_WE();
  initComponents();
  h.setDefaul
  ...
  psv.initComponents(){
   throw new Unsupported Operation Exception (“Not supported yet.”);
  }
```

Output;

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Not supported yet. at
>   customside.tab.CustomsideTab.initComponents(CustomsideTab.java:30) at
>   customside.tab.CustomsideTab.main(CustomsideTab.java:22)
>   C:\Users\kachconrad\AppData\Local\Netbeans\Cache\8.2\executionsnippets\run.xml:53:Javareturned:
>   1 BUILD FAILED (total time:2 seconds)

Comment: There are elements missing from your code but it looks like you are throwing an exception in class CustomsideTab's initComponents method. 
As it stands we can't really help you because we do not know what you are trying to do. Consider improving your question and explain to us what the expected behavior of your program is.

Comment: I’m making an online shopping app so which elements would you recommend I add to it?

Comment: You are creating an App. That gives us some valuable context, you should add that at the beginning of your question. However it is not enough for us to be able to help. From the name of the files from which the exception is thrown, it looks like the problem occurs during your application's setup. We need more details about what you are trying to do in this "initComponents" method. Check out [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for help on "how to ask questions".

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
try {
    initComponents();
} catch(UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    //Log error here
}
```